# JSON format list in couchDB

Tags: couchdb

I am writing a list for couchDB. All the documentation I have read assumes you would want to return data in html or plain text. I, however, need it to be returned in JSON format, in exactly the same way that a view would return (the application I am writing relies on this).

What is the correct way to have a list return its data in JSON format?

Answer (score 2):

Try [toJSON()](http://couchdb.readthedocs.org/en/latest/query-server/javascript.html#toJSON), see the [example](http://couchdb.readthedocs.org/en/latest/query-server/javascript.html#getRow).

Comment: Thanks for your response. Using toJSON() does cause the data to be sent in a JSON compatible format. (as does JSON.stringify() ). However, I need a JSON document to be sent, not just compatible data. I need the data returned as it would if it were just a view that I was querying.

Comment: There is no difference. Getting data from the pure map/reduce view should be exactly the same as compared to toJSON. How do you think the view server is sending you JSON? Although JSON is a subset of JavaScript types, it is not the same and server has to serialize in the same way as you do in list function. The list function is not serializing to JSON, giving the choice to you how to format your result. You can do what query to map/reduce does and run toJSON, or produce HTML, XML, plain text, ...any other format that you desire. And at the end you get text stream in REST-full protocol anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You need to format your output with `send` to mimmic a JSON output. Here is an example of how we do that in a real case:

```
function(head, req) {
    start({"headers": {"Content-Type": "application/json"}});
    var keys = {};
    while (row = getRow()) {

    //Code goes here

    send("{\"rows\":[");
    var init = true;
    for (var key in keys) {
        if (init) {
            send("\n");
            init = false;
        }
        else send(",\n");
        send("{\"key\": " + key + ",\"value\":");
        send("{\"first_val\":" + val1);
        send(", \"second_val\":" + val2);
        send(", \"third_val\":" + val3 + "}}");
    }
    send("\n]}");
}
```

In this way, the output of the list has the same format as the underlying view.